# Class [c in groovy

Tags: list, groovy

I have an app in grails which uses list contained in a map. I am using the list for simple string comparison in my code (value[0]=="something" for example).  the println showed the value[0] to be "something" but the test always failed. On further checking the class for value[0] [through value[0].getClass() ], I found the class of type [C.  Anybody has any clue on this.  The list is stored in a map and I am doing a map.each to get to the list (if that makes a difference). Here is my code and println output in my console.

### code

```
println "it.value[0] = " + it.value[0]
println "it.value[1] = " + it.value[1]
println "it.value[2] = " + it.value[2]

println "it.value[0] class = "+ it.value[0].getClass()
println "it.value[1] class = "+ it.value[1].getClass()
println "it.value[2] class = "+ it.value[2].getClass()
```

### output

```
it.value[0] = abc
it.value[1] = def
it.value[2] = ghi

it.value[0] class = class [C
it.value[1] class = class [C
it.value[2] class = class [C
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[C` is the Java field descriptor for a primitive character array (`char[]`).  These get shown when you examine the class name of an array type.

```
assert ("foo" as char[]).getClass().toString() == 'class [C'
```

The rules for how they get built are in the [JVM Specification section on Field Descriptors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.3.2).

Comment: +1 and you can use `it.value[ 0 ] as String` to get the `char[]` values back to a String